# Insert Image into Azure database as varbinary(max) using SSMS on local PC

Tags: azure, blob, ssms, varbinary, openrowset

I am doing some testing to see if I can use SSRS with an Azure database to create a simple report. I want to include a signature image at the bottom of the report that I am storing as a blob in the database.

The problem I have is I created the signature file on my laptop and saved it on the C drive. When I try to insert it into the table on Azure using the following statement:

```
insert into Signatures (ImageFile)
values (CAST(SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\Demos\SingnatureEg.png', SINGLE_BLOB) AS DefaultLogoImg));
```

As I am connected to the Azure database inside SSMS it cannot see the local file system. I ran the OPENROWSET separately using a connection to a locally stored database to generate the string. I copied and pasted it into the insert statement using a CAST to convert it to varbinary and the data inserted successfully. I used the following command:

```
insert into Signatures (ImageFile)
values (CAST('0x89504E470D0A....' AS VARBINARY(MAX)));
```

I hooked the image field up to an image object in my Report using the database field and the correct MIME Type of PNG and the image is not displaying correctly. I can only guess that the data didn't go into the table successfully.

How do I use the OPENROWSET command to insert the data into the Azure database when I can't access my local file system?